# Onclick show color in a div below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background

I have a list of colors which display in a 50px square boxes on my page.

What i would like to do is be able to click any of the color boxes and then it will show the clicked color in a div below.

```
<div style="background:#000000; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#c9c9c9; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#737373; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#424242; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#184880; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#3485bf; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#9ad8e6; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#006891; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#0f6769; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#009687; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#79c7c2; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#72b88a; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#669100; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#b5cf8c; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#74750e; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#c7c25f; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#faeb69; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#ffffa8; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#ffc824; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#f5652c; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#f0ab5d; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#e36b10; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#bd3a0f; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#996751; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#78502a; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#c2ae97; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#f4f4f4; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#a31d20; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#d4536c; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#e0d1dc; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#513d7a; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#9178ad; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
<div style="background:#d6cee0; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
```

And then when one of the colors is clicked it will display below

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I cant see jquery tag, -1 on everyone who uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code :

```
$("div[style]").click(function(){
    $("#result").css("background-color",$(this).css("background-color"));

})
```

Link for jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ACaX9/

Answer (score 1):

You can  do easily.
Insert a class in every div like this:

```
<div class="clickme" style="background:#000000; width:50px; height:50px; float: left; margin:4px"></div>
```

and in jquery you can do something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(){
       $('.clickme').click(function(){
      $('#result').html( rgb2hex($(this).css('background-color')));
   });

function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aV2RA/3/)