# Change colour of text on click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to jQuery and I have no idea about where to begin with this. On my webpage I have text and I want to put at the top four squares where the user can click on a square and this will change the colour of the text.

I am hoping to make the squares using CSS with the squares being red, yellow, green and black.

From this I need to create a colour picker using jQuery where the user will click a square and this will change the text into the appropriate colour.

Comment: what have you got so far? Where are you stuck? Can you show us some code, or even a working fiddle?

Comment: Why not use javascript instead?

Comment: @pattyd JQuery is just a Javascript Library, it makes our lives much easier =)

Comment: Check out the answer to this Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070845/onclick-show-color-in-a-div-below/15070935#15070935
Please be sure to google next time before posting thanks =D

Comment: @pandavenger this can easily be done my JavaScript though =D im sure Jquery would work too though!

Comment: @pattyd sure, you would just have to manually set the click events for each square, as well as each time more is added.

in JQuery all you need is `$(".classname").click(...)` which imo is much simpler

In the end we're all still using Javascript, my code will just look a lot cleaner.

Comment: Yeah I guess that makes sense! I don't know Jquery, but I have learned JavaScript, which is why I would favor that... It does sound easier to use Jquery though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/emical/1/edit

```
  <div class="picker" data-color="red"></div>
  <div class="picker" data-color="green"></div>
  <div class="picker" data-color="blue"></div>
  <div class="picker" data-color="black"></div>

  <div id="test">TEST DIV THAT WILL CHANGE COLOR</div>
```

...where eg: instead of `"red"` you can also use HEX: `"#f00"` or "#ff0000" or "rgb()", "rgba()"... etc etc :)

CSS:

```
.picker{

  cursor:pointer;
  margin:3px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  float:left;

}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.picker').each(function(){
  $(this).css({background: $(this).data('color')}); // set BG color for every element
}).click(function(){
  $('#test').css({color: $(this).data('color')});  // change Target's text color on click
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/
http://api.jquery.com/css/
http://api.jquery.com/click/

or like this:

```
$('.picker').each(function(){

  var myColor = $(this).data('color');

  $(this).css({background: myColor }).click(function(){
    $('#test').css({color: myColor});
  });

});
```